# Compare 2 strings with repetitive parts

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, compare, string-comparison

I am developing a speak reconition trainer and I want to get the hits and errors of the trainer result. I have the real sentence and the predicted sentence and I have something like this:

```
if real == predicted:
    hits += 1
else:
    errors += 1
```

My problem comes now... The predicted strings are with the form:

```
- 'command' 'time' 'unit'
```

Where 'unit' can be [minute,minutes,second,seconds]
And I want to count as hit the sentence with minute or minutes and second or secons. For example.

Real: stop five minutes and walk one second
Predicted1: stop five minute and walk one second
Predicted2: stop five minutes and walk one seconds
Predicted3: stop three minute and walk one seconds

Where Predicted1 and Predicted2 are hits and Predicted3 an error.
There are a fast way without turning all as lists and this kind of things

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be to strip the rightmost `s` from the units and then compare.

That is, if the unit is in variable `unit`, then `unit.rstrip('s')` returns the units without the rightmost `s`, and doesn't change the unit if it didn't have an `s` in the first place.